# Where to put a js function that converts a table into a DataTable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I'm using a wonderful library for jQuery named DataTables in Ruby on Rails 4 project. I'm a little confused about where to put a function that converts a  tag into a DataTable object (which sets its own classes and ids). I put this in the application.js file, because I would like this function to be available in most the application views, mostly of them are reports, however I don't know if this is the right place. It works, but the in the application.js comments says:

> // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll
>   appear at the bottom of the compiled file.

```
var tabla =  $('.tabla-reporte').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                autoPrint: false,
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body)
                        .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
                        .prepend(
                            '<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
                        );

                    $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                        .addClass( 'compact' )
                        .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                     var medias = win.document.querySelectorAll('[media="screen"]');
                     for(var i=0; i < medias.length;i++){ medias.item(i).media="all" };
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
```

Apparently there is not problem running that code, because if it doesn't find a class 'tabla-reporte' in the DOM of the current page loaded it won't do anything to it, but I just don't know if this complies with the "rails convention".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the following code to any of your `.js` files in the `assets` directory.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

This code will turn style any table that has `id = "myTable"` using DataTables. If you have some table that you don't want this style applied to, then just give it a different `id`. Protip: if you have multiple tables on the same page that should be styled with DataTables, then you can use `class = "myTable"` instead.

Don't add anything to your `application.js` file other than:

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

`application.js` is meant to store directives, not actual scripts. When your application starts, everything in your `assets` directory is going to be aggregated into one large script, so you don't have to worry about which `.js` file contains DataTables code unless you've set up controller specific assets.

Comment: That's the way I was looking for, and it works.
Just a detail: I'm using this directive: 
`//= require datatables`
Perhaps because I'm using a more recent of DataTables (1.10.8 with some new plugins) the way you wrote above doesn't work. 

Also, I noticed in head that is loading assets from other controllers! why?

Comment: You're loading assets from different controllers because (as I already wrote in the second paragraph of my answer) sprockets combines all of your assets into one big script. Are you using the JQuery DataTables gem, or are you trying to incorporate the DataTables plugin directly?

Comment: I copied into vendor/assets directory, jQuery DataTables gem doesn't have the most recent version and apparently doesn't include extensions that I require. I also tried via rails-assets, but i didn't find a proper version there.

Comment: Where did you put DataTables? In app/assets or vendor/assets?

Comment: `vendor/assets/DataTables`

Comment: Everything seems right to me... maybe just try //= require dataTables instead of all lowercase and if you're using dataTables.min, specify that in your directives as well as in application.css.